# Jenkins corrupted, need to know which files I need

Tags: windows, svn, jenkins

I am having issues with Jenkins that I am unable to resolve, and all the solutions I've found online I've used in the past, but are not helping.

I am on windows 2008r2, utilizing svn, jenkins version 1.407.

Initially the service failed, and was not resolved with past methods. In the past I have successfully troubleshoot Jenkins by killing hung processes, restoring the war file, ect.

I have attempted a new install with bringing over the files in the jobs folder. The end result was a partially functioning Jenkins would attempt a build it would report no change and not update.

What I'm trying to determine is a list of files/folders beyond the jobs folder that I need to move to the new install. The initial install predates me and was Hudson. The folder has a number of obviously obsolete files and folders (both a jenkins.war and a hudson.war)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Jenkins home folder and collect:

- all `./*.xml` files in - these are configuration files for plugins and jenkins itself
- `users/*` in case you have security enabled
- `subversion-credentials/**` and `secrets/**` for any kind of keys provided in jenkins to access svn or other resources
- `plugins/*.*pi` folder for all plugins - you don't need to have the unpacked folders
- `jobs/*/config.xml` - to retrieve all job configurations; `jobs/*/nextBuildNumber` if you care to continue build numbers
- plugins may create additional folders which you may want to use

with that you should recreate Jenkins as it was. Pay especially attention to `config.xml` file in root folder - this holds main jenkins configuration. If your issue reproduces on new system most likely a plugin is cause for problems - in that case review log files most likely you will find out which plugin causes trouble.

You didn't indicate if you tried new setup with same version of Jenkins or newer one; if you are using newest version it may be that ssh key handling / svn authentication for each job needs to be updated as somewhen in last few months authentication / security handling changed. Best is to look into Jenkins release log.

I'm using Jenkins 1.55x on CentOS installed as RPM; given that it is a webapp I assume Windows 1.4x setup is similar.

Comment: I was installing the new version.  I had tried most of what you had suggested earlier on with little success. The end fix that finally worked was a complete uninstall. re-install with the new version and then restoring the old version that was backed up. All other permutations didn't seem to work.